# Убрать отступы между background

Tags: html, css, background, отступы

Есть галерея
[image]

Вот код

```
<style>
.galleryPage {width:90%;max-width:800px;min-width:800px;width:800px;margin:0 auto;padding-top:2em;}
.sortBy{float:left;}
.linkSortAct {border-bottom:1px dashed #003080;color:#003080;}
.linkSort:hover {color:#003080;opacity:0.8;}
.galleryLoad {width:80%;float:left;padding-left:2em;}


.aGalleryImg{width:33%;float:left;height:18em;background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat;margin:0;padding:0;}
.aGalleryImg:hover {opacity:0.6;cursor:pointer;}

.aGalleryAddBtn {margin-top:1em;cursor:pointer;width:100%;text-align:center;font-size:1.2em;background:#d9d9d9;height:2em;padding-top:10px;}
.aGalleryAddBtn:hover{opacity:0.7;}
</style>    
<div class="galleryLoad" id="galleryLoad">  
    <div class="aGalleryImg" id="img2" style=" background-image: url(gallery/original/IMG_1.JPG);"></div>
    <div class="aGalleryImg" id="img3" style=" background-image: url(gallery/original/IMG_10.JPG);"></div>
    <div class="aGalleryImg" id="img4" style=" background-image: url(gallery/original/IMG_11.JPG);"></div>
    <div class="aGalleryImg" id="img5" style=" background-image: url(gallery/original/IMG_12.JPG);"></div>
    <div class="aGalleryImg" id="img6" style=" background-image: url(gallery/original/IMG_13.JPG);"></div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Каким образом можно сделать обтекание без пропусков , что бы получилось как на картинке , желательно без привлечения javascript , только средствами css

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

С помощью колонок:

Поддержка браузерами [97.6%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)

```css
.galery{
   -webkit-column-count:2;  
    -moz-column-count:2;  
    column-count:3;

    /*Отступ между колонками*/
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px;  
    -moz-column-gap: 0px;  
    column-gap: 0px;

    /*Отступ между картинками*/
    line-height:0;
}

.galery img{
     width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="galery">
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" >
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/280/any" > 
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/180/any" >
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/380/any" >   
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/230/any" >   
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Например с помощью [masonry grid](http://masonry.desandro.com/):

```js
$('.galleryLoad').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.aGalleryImg',
  percentPosition: true
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.aGalleryImg {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<!-- or -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
  
  <div class="galleryLoad" id="galleryLoad">
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/300/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/500/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/400/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/300/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/300/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/100/400/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/300/any" alt=""></div>
  </div>
```

Такой еще вариант с flex:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.aGalleryImg {
  width: 33%;
}

.galleryLoad {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 650px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="galleryLoad" id="galleryLoad">
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/300/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/500/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/400/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/300/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/300/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/any" alt=""></div>
    <div class='aGalleryImg'><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/300/any" alt=""></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: *желательно без привлечения javascript*

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, "желательно"  ж не "только"